# Linq to XML Get newer date element

Tags: xml, linq, date, get

```
    <Itinerary Id="34" Code="2010STAN" Modified="2010-09-07 16:58:35">
<Itinerary Id="34" Code="2010STAN" Modified="2010-11-12 15:53:13">
<Itinerary Id="34" Code="2010STAN" Modified="2011-11-12 15:53:13">
```

I get that XML. and requirement is:

I want to get newer date / Large Date from Linq to XML query. for instance i want to get last node."2011-11-12 15:53:13"

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the whole element, or just the date itself? For the date, it's easy:

```
var maxDate = list.Select(x => (DateTime) x.Attribute("Modified"))
                      .Max();
```

To get the element *containing* the latest date, you'd either have to sort them and take the first element, e.g.

```
var maxElement = list.OrderByDescending(x => (DateTime) x.Attribute("Modified"))
                     .First();
```

or use something like [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq):

```
var maxElement = list.MaxBy(x => (DateTime) x.Attribute("Modified"));
```

Comment: At least one object must implement IComparable.

My Code is  : '   var t = (from resp_tourCodes in xmlDoc.Descendants("Itinerary")
                     select resp_tourCodes).OrderByDescending(x => x.Attribute("Modified")).First();'

Comment: @Muhammad: Well yes, you haven't used the code I gave you... you need to cast the attribute to a `DateTime`, as per my answer. Note that your query expression is pretty pointless - you can just use `var t = xmlDoc.Descendants("Itinerary").OrderByDescending(x => (DateTime) x.Attribute("Modified")).First();`